# Is there a way to have an interface method do an operation over variable size structs?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Having various C# structs of varying sizes, most of them do have one member in common: a CRC field of type `ushort`. This field is always the last in each struct. (Yes, we are doing some hardware programming here)

So, I have an IHasCRC interface which implements the required calculations in the default methods. yet, I didn't figure out a way to have the interface method access the structs bytes without "external help". The CRC routines all access the data through a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` .

See what I mean:

```
public interface IHasCrc
{
    public ushort CalculateCrc(ReadOnlySpan<byte> dataBuffer)
    {
        return CRC.ComputeChecksum(dataBuffer[0..^2]);
    }

    public bool IsCrcValid(ReadOnlySpan<byte> dataBuffer)
    {
        ushort crc = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>(dataBuffer[^2..])[0];
        ushort crc_computed = CRC.ComputeChecksum(dataBuffer[0..^2]);
        return crc == crc_computed;
    }
}
```

For this work, the caller must provide the data buffer (the struct cast to a read only span of type byte) instead of the method implementation casting from ´this´. Like this:

```
HWSTRUCT_xxx data; // ... somewhere initialized
data.CRC = (data as IHasCrc).CalculateCrc(StructExtensions.AsSpan<HWSTRUCT_xxx>(ref data));
```

The `AsSpan` method does the magic through `MemoryMarshal`'s Cast and CreateReadOnlySpan, which requires a `ref` reference, thus can't pass `this`.

How could I implement a CalculateCrc (and IsCrcValid) method in the interface that does all that without the need to pass the Span as parameter?? Remember that all structs have different sizes and thus the CRC field is on different byte positions in the struct, but it's always the last 2 bytes.

**Update:**
After some discussions online and a bit of researching, I came to a little improvement:

```
public interface IHasCrc2<T> where T : struct
{
    private unsafe ReadOnlySpan<byte> GetSpan(ref T myStruct)
    {
        return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref myStruct), Unsafe.SizeOf<T>());
    }

    public ushort CalculateCrc();

    public ushort CalculateCrcImplementation(ref T me)
    {
        return CRC.ComputeChecksum(this.GetSpan(ref me));
    }

    public bool IsCrcValid();
}
```

With that interface, details are better hidden and easier to implement, although not yet totally transparent.

Implementing structs are like this, it all comes down to implementing the two methods of the interface, with basically a one liner each, only replacing the struct name. Unfortunately boxing is needed to access the default implementation in the interface. Although this might go into an helper method I guess and thus avoid boxing.

```
public struct HWSTRUCT_xxx : IHasCrc2<HWSTRUCT_xxx>
{
    public HWSTRUCT_base Base;
    // other data
    public ushort CRC;

    public ushort CalculateCrc()
    {
        return this.CRC = (this as IHasCrc2<HWSTRUCT_xxx>).CalculateCrcImplementation(ref this);
    }

    public bool IsCrcValid()
    {
        return (this as IHasCrc2<HWSTRUCT_xxx>).CalculateCrcImplementation(ref this) == this.CRC;
    }
}
```

Comment: `MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, ushort>` -- use `BinaryPrimitives.ReadUint16LittleEndian`/`BigEndian`

Comment: Normally, the right place to do the CRC is a layer lower than your structs -- after the struct is written out to a byte array (before it's sent), or after it's read in to a byte array (before it's deserialized). Don't try and implement it after the data has been parsed to a struct: that's too late. The CRC is normally over the raw bytes which are sent/received over the wire, and not once they have been parsed to higher-level constructs (such as big/little-endian ints, strings, etc)

Comment: ReadUint16whatever doesnt help at all, since I have no access to the byte array through the interface (see code in question).

Comment: That was just a nit: the "right" answer here means not doing that at all, but if you find yourself doing something similar in future, use the methods on `BinaryPrimitives` to turn sequences of bytes into numbers, rather than using `MemoryMarshal.Cast`

Comment: Point is: the struct is never copied to a byte array but rather accessed as a readonly byte array so it is sent over the wire.

Comment: In that case, you're missing a step, which is writing the struct to a byte array. Don't just blit it unless there's very good reason: you're hamstrung by the machine's endianness for starters, and can't support anything other than basic primitives. You also need to be careful about packing, alignment, etc. Either way, the point at which you calculate the CRC is *after* you've turned the struct into an series of bytes, not before: even if you're streaming bytes out rather than collecting them in an array/span first, calculate the CRC as you go, and send it last

Comment: Thats why I want to wrap the CRC funcionality into an interface (as a struct it cant inherit as I would normally do). After filling the struct with data, have itself calculate the CRC (or verify it) so the code using it doesnt have to deal with the details.

Comment: The structs members are endian correct already, so there is absolutely no need to ever copy them to a byte array just so it can be sent. Thats a unnecessary step.

Comment: And I'm saying that is the wrong way to go about it. The CRC is calculated from the bytes you send, and isn't a property of the struct itself. It's helpful to make sure you're clear on the layers you have: you'll have some sort of framing, which contains any start/stop bytes, length, command id, etc etc, payload, and CRC. The CRC is part of the framing (and often incorporates more than just the payload). The payload is the bit which is turned into one of your structs. The CRC is not part of the payload.

Comment: "*Thats a unnecessary step.*" -- it will bite you, I promise. I speak from lots of experience doing exactly this :)

Comment: Your idea is to have all structs basically without the CRC member, and when sending calculate the CRC over the data (struct or byte array, doesn't make a difference). Would be good and fine (although not nice because it still keeps the CRC out of the structs and some code higher up has to know about it. But what about the CRC validation? How would I go along with this then?

Comment: The opposite: data is validated as it's received, before the payload is parsed. The same point that you check that the length is correct for the command id, the command id is known, etc etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226875/discussion-between-hefaistos68-and-canton7).

Comment: "*and some code higher up has to know about it*" -- it's code *lower down*, not higher up. Lower-level code gets increasingly close to the hardware. It's ugly that you're trying to teach the higher-level structs about CRC's, when it's a framing problem: the payload should have no knowledge of how it's framed

Comment: With your edit, you're still boxing the struct for exactly zero reason: you're not using the boxed struct at all! There's no point in using DIM here -- use a utility class.

Comment: Yeah, I am not happy with it anyway. Too much code duplicated, too much details exposed.